# Configurar Reply-To em formulário

Tags: php, formulário

Olá,

Estou trabalhando em um formulário PHP onde preciso configurar o email do remetente no campo 'Reply-To: ' . $from , dessa forma, a resposta ao email será direta para quem preencheu o formulário. Segue o código PHP atual.

```
    <?php

    $from = 'Nome <nome@email>';

    $sendTo = 'Nome <nome@email>';

    $subject = 'Formulário de Contato';

    $fields = array('name' => 'Nome', 'email' => 'E-mail', 'phone' => 'Telefone', 'empresa' => 'Empresa', 'assunto' => 'Assunto', 'message' => 'Mensagem');

    $okMessage = 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso! Em breve lhe retornaremos.';

    $errorMessage = 'Erro no envio da mensagem. Por favor, tente novamente.';

    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    try
    {

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Formulário está vazio.');

    $emailText = "Formulário de Contato\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
    }

    else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
    }
```

Abaixo, segue HTML:

```
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
    <div class="messages"></div>
    <div class="controls">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_name">Nome *</label>
    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu nome *" required data-error="Por favor, preencha este campo.">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_email">E-mail *</label>
    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail *" required data-error="Por favor, digite um e-mail válido.">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_phone">Telefone</label>
    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu telefone">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_empresa">Empresa</label>
    <input id="form_empresa" type="text" name="empresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome de sua empresa">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_assunto">Assunto *</label>
    <select id="form_assunto" name="assunto" class="form-control" required data-error="Por favor, selecione um assunto.">
    <option value="" selected="">Selecione um assunto *</option>
    <option value="Solicitação de Orçamento">Solicitação de Orçamento</option>
    <option value="Trabalhe Conosco">Trabalhe Conosco</option>
    <option value="Administrativo/Financeiro">Administrativo/Financeiro</option>
    <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
    <option value="Diretoria">Diretoria</option>
    <option value="Dúvidas, críticas ou sugestões">Dúvidas, críticas ou sugestões</option>
    </select>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>                 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_message">Mensagem *</label>
    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem *" rows="4" required data-error="Por favor, preencha este campo."></textarea>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Enviar">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="text-muted">Campos terminados em <strong>*</strong> são obrigatórios.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO! Qual é o erro ou a sua dúvida exatamente?

Comment: Obrigado, Leonardo! Eu gostaria que, ao responder o email enviado pelo formulário, no campo Destinatário constasse o email da pessoa que entrou em contato através do site. Já tentei alterar o 'Reply-To: ' . $from colocando a variável de email, mas como não dominio php e não entendo de array (peguei este script pronto na web), não estou conseguindo fazê-lo.

Comment: Precisaria ver o HTML do formulário, mas me parece que ele não está passando as informações de `from` e `to` pro PHP porque eles estão setados manualmente.

Comment: Leonardo, editei a pergunta e inseri o HTML do formulário... se puder ajudar, agradeço! valeu

Comment: Tente substituir os 3 `$from` na linha depois do `$header... ` por `$_POST["email"]` e veja se funciona

Comment: Muito obrigado, Leonardo! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Por nada! Para fins de documentação, coloquei a resposta abaixo na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituia o trecho de código assim:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $_POST["email"],
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"],
    'Return-Path: ' . $_POST["email"],
    );
```

Você estava setando manualmente o valor do `$from` no começo do código. Dessa forma, você passará a pegar o valor que foi enviado dinamicamente pelo `POST` do `form`.

Comment: entendi, era mais simples do que eu pensava! valeu :D